# How to do local sorting and filtering with React Admin?

Tags: sorting, filter, react-admin

I created a dashboard using React-Admin, in that application when I am trying to sort table based on a specific column, a fetch request is made to the backend and querystring is passed along with the URL, currently my backend is not setup to read querystring data, same thing happens when I try to search using some text, a request is made to the backend and the search string is sent along with the querystring. What I want to do is find a way to sort or filter locally without making any request to the backend. Hope this is possible, if anyone can suggest me a way to go forward.